# How to delete duplicate with row_number() window function while keeping the latest row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to keep the latest or even one of the duplicate records in my table using `row_number()` window function by adding max or something. How should I modify my code? This func deletes all the duplicate records.

I tried the statement below so far:

```
DELETE FROM employee
 WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id
                         FROM (SELECT employee_id,
                                      ROW_NUMBER() 
                                           OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id 
                                                     ORDER BY employee_id) AS row_num
                                 FROM employee) t
                        WHERE row_num > 1)
```

Comment: Hard to believe this is the correct idea here. Could you please show some sample data and the expected results after the intended deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is, that you are deleting with `employee_id IN (...)`, so it always deletes every employee with this number. You need to delete by row number.

Here is an example for your case, please let me know if it works you :)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        employee.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY employee_id
            ORDER BY employee_id
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        employee
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```